# Erro na minha query ifnull. porque?

Tags: sql, mysqli

Query que esta marcada de vermelho não funciona e a azul funciona!

```sql
SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(id_rela_post), ifnull(qt_vezes, 0), para FROM rela_post GROUP BY para) post_detalhe on posts.id_post = post_detalhe.para
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aparece algum erro na tela?

Comment: #1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a '(qt_vezes, 0), para FROM rela_post GROUP BY para) post_detalhe on posts.id_post ' na linha 1

Comment: Falta uma vírgula após o `COUNT(id_rela_post)`

Comment: n falta virgula, acabei de colocar e deu Erro

Comment: Coloque código como texto, e não como imagem.

Comment: Depois de por a virgula, deu o mesmo erro ou foi erro novo? Tem como colocar as querys ao invés de fotos/imagens. Somos uma comunidade de programadores, fica mais fácil para copiar e testar do que termos o trabalho de ter que ficar vendo imagens e digitando tudo novamente. Se puder ajudar quem lhe ajuda tudo vai fluir melhor.

Comment: ja colei o post, mas nao entendi q diferença faz ter a query se nao tem o banco!

Comment: O campo `qt_vezes` precisa estar no group by.... o `ifnull` não é uma função de agregação.

Comment: o qt_vezes  ele e o AS     do COUNT(id_rela_post) quero que retorna 0 ao invez do null

Comment: @AKU é necessário ter em texto, pois a chance de reescrevermos seu código com um novo erro (no caso o nosso) é grande. Colocando seu código em texto podemos copiá-lo **como ele é**. Considere incluir todas as suas tentativas e os códigos de erro de cada uma delas dentro da pergunta para tentarmos reverter os votos negativos e tornar mais fácil corrigir o problema.

Answer (score 2):

O correto seria colocar o `IFNULL(COUNT(id_rela_post), 0)`, ao invés de colocar no alias da pesquisa.

Comment: fiz isso deu erro! mesmo assim obg pela ajuda!